# FluentValidation Rulefor( ...reading a COMBO)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, fluentvalidation

What is the right way to check if a Combo has a value using the C# FluentValidation Rulefor() for MVC3 ??

I have a Date of Birth set of 3 comboboxes

```
    @Html.DatePickerDropDowns(Html.FieldNameFor(x => x.DateOfBirthDay),
                              Html.FieldNameFor(x => x.DateOfBirthMonth),
                              Html.FieldNameFor(x => x.DateOfBirthYear),
                                 DateTime.Now.Year - 110,
                                 DateTime.Now.Year,
                                 Model.DateOfBirthDay,
                                 Model.DateOfBirthMonth,
                                 Model.DateOfBirthYear)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirthDay)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirthMonth)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirthYear)
```

Each of the combo displays "DAY" or "Month" or "Year"
and they each have their related list.

So I would like to check if the user has selected one of the values from 0..31.

```
   RuleFor(x => x.DateOfBirthDay).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Day is required");
   RuleFor(x => x.DateOfBirthMonth).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Month is required");
   RuleFor(x => x.DateOfBirthYear).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Year is required");
```

For example the DateOfBirthDay HTML output Combo looks like this:

```
  "0" - Day  
  "1" - 1  
  "2" - 2  
   ...till 31
```

When i run the ModelState.IsValid it does NOT pick up the fact that the user did not touch any of combo values, leaving the index as "0".

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what "DatePickerDropdowns" is, but FluentValidation has special logic for this case.  Use .NotEmpty()  and instead of setting Day to 0, leave it blank.  Using default DropDownListFor, you would set the option parameter to "Day" and this would happen automatically.

Did you write the DatePickerDropDowns helper?  I would not have implemented it this way.  I would have used a single DateTime, and then created an EditorTemplate that creates the 3 dropdowns for this type (if it's the only DateTime you have, otherwise use UIHint to specify a custom template).

Comment: It's part of an open source I'm using, but i might just change that to the standard way (as you mentioned). thanks.

Answer (score 0):

//Would something like this work..? I assume that you are looking if it equals "..." ?

```
string somestring = new string('.',3);
this.RuleFor(x => x.MyComboList).Equals(somestring);
```

//or

```
this.RuleFor(x => x.MyComboList).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("...");
```

Comment: Not really, the first item is hard coded and looks like "Day".

Comment: I need to see what your actual inValid strings are from there why not create an string[] array.. if I see what you have exactly without the "..." from what you have it looks like a hard coded string..sorry